# How to get device ID on tablet Android 4.0.3 like android-xxx

Tags: android

My device ID in ABOUT PHONE is `unknown`, so I can't get ID by API `android.os.Build.SERIAL;`

I tried to get Mac Address as Device ID, but it's not working when I turn the wifi adapter off.

I know there is a device ID like `android-xxx` when I connect my device to wireless network, how can I get that device ID???

Please help me :D

Answer (score 1):

```
 String deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

You ll need this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Although I am not sure why you need it and I'd recommend you read this first anyway
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html